# Visual Studio Code Plugins (Format / Spell Check)

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, vscode-extensions

Using the new Visual Studio Code editor vs 1. This is **not** the full Visual Studio IDE but their atom.io based code editor. I would like to install plugins specifically for spell check and formatting my code. How can I do this?

I've followed instructions here: [Is there a command for formatting HTML in the Atom editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189068/is-there-a-command-for-formatting-html-in-the-atom-io-editor)
but realized that I do not have a install plugin command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been a few months since the question was asked (and answered), but thankfully, things have changed!

## [VSCode now support extensions!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/11/17/announcing-visual-studio-code-beta.aspx)

Here's a relevant excerpt from the above blog post:

> ### Extension Marketplace/Gallery
>
> To complement the extensibility mechanism, we have also launched an in product gallery and web based extension marketplace.  These allow you to discover and install extensions.  To open this up in VSCode, simply hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and select <kbd>Extensions: Install Extensions</kbd>.
>
> Alternatively, you can browse the Extension Marketplace at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/#VSCode.

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

I gave the marketplace a quick search and easily found multiple extensions for spelling and source formatting, but I'll forego making any specific recommendations since everyone's requirements are different.

For anyone looking to write their own extensions for VSCode, take a look at the documentation for [extending VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview), as it has a lot of the information you'd need to start writing your own extensions.

Lastly, thanks to [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2131717/daniel-lemke) for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224784/visual-studio-code-plugins-format-spell-check#comment55368706_30227105).  It helped me find the information I needed, but to save future visitors some time, I thought it was worth sharing my findings.

Answer (score 7):

Plugin support is not currently enabled in the VSCode editor. The development team were not happy with the plugin API, so they have disabled them until further work can be made on this.

For more information, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30006220/495328

Comment: Does anyone know if there has been any work done on plugin subsystem ?

Comment: Plugins are now supported: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752408-plugin-system?tracking_code=a00b8c6dc01b4f0d7b242d786d586d47

Comment: @DanielLemke Thanks for that link in your comment.  It gave me all the information I needed, which I compiled together and put into my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34697704/1187982).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use **[Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)** and **[Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker)** for the purposes.

Here are some use case for **spell check**:

Load a CSS, JavaScript, Text, etc. file. Words not in the dictionary files will have a ***squiggly underline*** below the text.

[image]

To see the list of suggestions just click on the  (lightbulb) in the left hand margin. You have the option to add your own words to the workspace dictionary.

[image]