# How can we edit Rust files in VSCode?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

I like the new VSCode and would love to use it for Rust programming. Are there any rust plugins available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Support for Rust syntax coloring will be in the next VSCode update.

"VSCode is based on Atom". This is not accurate. VSCode is built on top of the [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) (was the AtomShell), the editor and workbench are a totally different code based (the [Monaco editor](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco))

Comment: Rust syntax coloring is  now included in VS Code 0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

For now VSCode doesn't support plugins [Visual Studio Code Plugins (Format / Spell Check)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224784/visual-studio-code-plugins-format-spell-check)

I know that there is Rust plugin for Atom IDE https://github.com/zargony/atom-language-rust and VSCode is based on Atom.

Comment: can we install this atom plugin to VSCode?